# line integral if the path is indepedent

Tags: integration

[image: The Question]

I am confused how to use the paraboloid and plane into the F.

Comment: Please don’t include critical information in an image. It’s not searchable, is inaccessible to people with screen readers, and doesn’t show up in summaries. If you don’t take your own time to enter your question, why should you expect anyone to take their time to answer it?

Comment: I’ve heard of differential forms being exact and vector fields being irrotational, but I can’t recall a line integral being called exact.

Comment: Hint: if the answer to part b is “yes,” then you can use any path between the two points.

Comment: I do not know what is $C$? $\Bbb C$ over whole complex numbers it's integral exists, and is this what is meant by "exact"? Though you explain what you don't understand I don't under stand what you are attempting to do, trying to solve the problem.

Comment: @marshalcraft $C$ is the curve along which the line integral is to be computed.

Comment: @amd , i have proved that is path independent , so I can use the potential of F to find out the value.

Comment: let f be the potential of F,  the value = f(-1,0,0) -  f(0,0,0). Is it correct?

Comment: The point $(0,0,0)$ does not lie on that path.

Comment: it lies on the intersection.

Comment: The path is the intersection of two surfaces so every point of the path must satisfy the equation of both surfaces. The point $(-1,0,0)$ satisfies the equation of the paraboloid and the equation of the plane, but the point $(0,0,0)$ satisfies neither equation. Neither surface contains the origin, so their intersection cannot contain the origin.

Comment: so it cannot find the answer for (c)

Comment: If the original problem said $(0,0,0)$ I would suspect a typo or misprint and that it should have been $(0,1,0)$ which would make more sense since it does lie on the path.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

We see that:
$$
f(x,y,z)=\int (1+z+\sin y)dx=x(1+z+\sin y)+G(y,z)
$$
is a candidate for the potential function of $\mathbf{F}$, and a simple inspection shows that , for $G=0$,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x \cos y \qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=x
$$

so $f(x,y,z)=x(1+z+\sin y)$ is really the potential function and $ (1+z+\sin y)dx+  x \cos y \,dy +x dz$ is an exact form and this answer, I suppose, the first question.  The other answers come as consequences. (But note that the point $(0,0,0)$ is not in the paraboliod nor in the plane)